# FOR XML EXPLICIT

Tags: sql-server, xml, explicit

Say I have this setup:

```
-- tables
declare @main table (id int, name varchar(20))
declare @subA table (id int, mid int, name varchar(20))
declare @subA1 table (id int, subAid int, name varchar(20))
declare @subA2 table (id int, subAid int, name varchar(20))
declare @subB table (id int, mid int, name varchar(20))

-- sample data
insert @main values (1, 'A')
insert @main values (2, 'B')
insert @SubA values (1, 1, 'A')
insert @SubA values (2, 1, 'B')
insert @SubA values (3, 2, 'C')
insert @SubA1 values (1, 1, 'A')
insert @SubA2 values (1, 2, 'A')
insert @SubB values (1, 1, 'A')
insert @SubB values (2, 1, 'B')
insert @SubB values (3, 2, 'C')

-- results
select m.id, m.name, a.name, a1.name, a2.name, b.name
from @main m
left outer join @SubA a on m.id = a.mid
left outer join @SubA1 a1 on a.id = a1.subAid
left outer join @SubA2 a2 on a.id = a2.subAid
left outer join @SubB b on m.id = b.mid
```

This returns:

```
1   A   A   A   NULL    A
1   A   A   A   NULL    B
1   A   B   NULL    A   A
1   A   B   NULL    A   B
2   B   C   NULL    NULL    C
```

If I use "for xml auto" then I get:

```
<m id="1" name="A">
  <a name="A">
    <a1 name="A">
      <a2>
        <b name="A" />
        <b name="B" />
      </a2>
    </a1>
  </a>
  <a name="B">
    <a1>
      <a2 name="A">
        <b name="A" />
        <b name="B" />
      </a2>
    </a1>
  </a>
</m>
<m id="2" name="B">
  <a name="C">
    <a1>
      <a2>
        <b name="C" />
      </a2>
    </a1>
  </a>
</m>
```

However, this isn't what I need. What I want to show is that @main is the main table which has two children: @subA and @SubB. @SubA in turn also has two children: @SubA1 and @SubA2, so I would like to get back:

```
<m id="1" name="A">
  <a name="A">
    <a1 name="A"></a1>
    <a2></a2>    
  </a>
  <a name="B">
    <a1></a1>
    <a2 name="A"></a2>    
  </a>
  <b name="A" />
  <b name="B" />  
</m>
<m id="2" name="B">
  <a name="C">
    <a1></a1>
    <a2></a2>    
  </a>
  <b name="C" />  
</m>
```

I'm pretty sure that I will have to use "for xml explicit", but out of all the attempts I have tried so far I haven't been able to get the format that I need.

Can anyone show an example query that will return the data in the required format?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?? SQL Server 2005 and up have FOR XML PATH which is a lot easier than EXPLICIT....

Comment: I can't guarantee that it will be on a 2005+ box as there are still some people who run it on 2000 so it has to work for both platforms. Also, I don't think FOR XML PATH would give me the flexibility needed to produce the output I listed above. I'd be happy to be proved wrong though!

Answer (score 2):

You can also re-write query to control the xml output, Google `nested FOR XML QUERY`. Here is an example using `FOR XML AUTO`, you could probably get better control using this technique with `FOR XML PATH`.

```
-- tables
declare @main table (id int, name varchar(20))
declare @subA table (id int, mid int, name varchar(20))
declare @subA1 table (id int, subAid int, name varchar(20))
declare @subA2 table (id int, subAid int, name varchar(20))
declare @subB table (id int, mid int, name varchar(20))

-- sample data
insert @main values (1, 'm(1)')
insert @main values (2, 'm(2)')
insert @SubA values (1, 1, 'm(1)/a(1)')
insert @SubA values (2, 1, 'm(1)/a(2)')
insert @SubA values (3, 2, 'm(2)/a(3)')
insert @SubA1 values (1, 1, 'a(1)/a1(1)')
insert @SubA2 values (1, 1, 'a(1)/a2(1)')
insert @SubA2 values (2, 2, 'a(2)/a2(2)')
insert @SubB values (1, 1, 'm(1)/b(1)')
insert @SubB values (2, 1, 'm(1)/b(2)')
insert @SubB values (3, 2, 'm(2)/b(3)')

SELECT  m.id
       ,m.name
       ,( SELECT    [name]
                   ,( SELECT    [name]
                      FROM      @subA1 AS a1
                      WHERE     a1.subAid = a.id
                    FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
                    )
                   ,( SELECT    [name]
                      FROM      @subA2 AS a2
                      WHERE     a2.subAid = a.id
                    FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
                    )
          FROM      @SubA AS a
          WHERE     m.id = a.mid
        FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
        )
       ,( SELECT    [name]
          FROM      @SubB AS b
          WHERE     m.id = b.mid
        FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
        )
FROM    @main AS m
FOR XML AUTO
```

Returns:

```
<m id="1" name="m(1)">
  <a name="m(1)/a(1)">
    <a1 name="a(1)/a1(1)" />
    <a2 name="a(1)/a2(1)" />
  </a>
  <a name="m(1)/a(2)">
    <a2 name="a(2)/a2(2)" />
  </a>
  <b name="m(1)/b(1)" />
  <b name="m(1)/b(2)" />
</m>
<m id="2" name="m(2)">
  <a name="m(2)/a(3)" />
  <b name="m(2)/b(3)" />
</m>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's a bit "messy" in terms of the original sql statement, but it does provide the output I want so this may be the answer I go for in the end.

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't be able to use this approach. There may be multiple "A1" records returned from the query and you can't return multiple rows as part of a nested subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, this doesn't answer your question, but in general I've found the UNION approach with XML EXPLICIT a good approach, as the SQL is much clearer to read. An example is here:

http://jdixon.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/sql_2000s_for_xml_explicit_vs_sql_2005s_for_xml_path.htm

Comment: Thank you, I've also seen several examples that use UNION queries, I'm just not sure if that's what I need or not!