# SQL and XML and complex JOINs

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to build a SQL query or procedure to build a complex XML result from several tables. This is in SQL Server 2008 R2.

So the XML i want to return is along the lines of

```
<requests>
  <request>
    <field one/>
    <field two/>
    <person>
      <personinfo/>
      <roleinfo/>
      <addrinfo/>
      <!-- don't want <item> elements here -->
    </person>
    <person>
      <personinfo/>
      <roleinfo/>
      <addrinfo/>
      <!-- don't want <item> elements here -->
    </person>
    <item><iteminfo/></item> <- i want <item> elements to show up here
    <item><iteminfo/></item>
    <item><iteminfo/></item>
  </request>
  <request>
    ...
  </request>
<requests>
```

I can get it to work without the `<item/>` rows, but when i try to join the `<item/>` rows into the final result, it joins them into the `<person/>` elements instead of the `<request/>` elements. This is probably a problem with my understanding or use of joins, but i'm treading water at this point.

The SQL that creates the XML without the `<item/>` elements looks something like the following.

```
select actor-fields, person-fields, role-fields, address-fields
into #tempperson from actor
left join person on actor.personid = person.personid
left join address on address.personid = person.personid
left join role on role.personid = person.personid
order by personid

select request-fields
into #tempreq from request
order by requestid

select *
from #tempreq as request
left join #tempperson as person on person.requestid = request.requestid
order by request.requestid
for xml auto, root('requests'), elements;
```

What i need is SQL that will return the desired XML. If i add another join to the above SQL, it adds the `<item/>` nodes inside the `<person/>` nodes, which isn't what i want.

I've read articles on XML AUTO, but the examples don't return a nesting structure like this. Maybe i'm going about this all wrong. Any guidance on this?

Comment: Where do you select the items?

Comment: Sorry @Byron, yeah, the SQL i had up there is boiled down from what i got that was working (without the items). Since i don't have SQL that works for items, i didn't include any. I'll edit the question to be clearer, i hope. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in how the data is presented in XML has it's own behavior different from regular SQL when modeling it.  The thing to remember is you can position nodes yourself with 'For xml path...' HOWEVER... if you are joining to a table that are referenced with joins that have relationships that show children.  SQL may try to force XML elements on you when you don't want them.  You can handle this nesting problem in a few ways if the data is complex:

1. Dump it to a temp table thus making MOOT any ASSUMED relationships SQL thought about your data.  Now it thinks it is all one dataset and ripe to do with it as you wish.  You don't care about the relationships, you threw them out and decided to model it manually.
2. Do nested selects that scope out to a larger body.  You can have the nested selects be inside a larger xml body as well.  I have used this as well.

Try this self extracting example:

```sql
declare @Person Table ( personID int identity, person varchar(8));

insert into @Person values ('Brett'),('Sean'),('Chad'),('Michael'),('Ray'),('Erik'),('Queyn');

declare @Orders table ( OrderID int identity, PersonID int, Desciption varchar(32), Amount int);

insert into @Orders values (1, 'Shirt', 20),(1, 'Shoes', 50),(2, 'Shirt', 22),(2, 'Shoes', 52),(3, 'Shirt', 20),(3, 'Shoes', 50),(3, 'Hat', 20),(4, 'Shirt', 20),(5, 'Shirt', 20),(5, 'Pants', 30),
(6, 'Shirt', 20),(6, 'RunningShoes', 70),(7, 'Shirt', 22),(7, 'Shoes', 40),(7, 'Coat', 80)

Select 
    p.person as "@Person"
,   o.Desciption as "Order/@Description"
,   o.Amount as "Order/*"
from @Person p
    join @Orders o on p.personID = o.PersonID
for xml path('Person'), root('People')
-- this will present my data nice but you may have more complex data than this

if object_id('tempdb..#Temp') is not null
    drop table #temp

Select 
    p.person 
,   o.Desciption
,   o.Amount
into #Temp
from @Person p
    join @Orders o on p.personID = o.PersonID

Select
    person as "@Person"
,   Desciption as "Order/@Description"
,   Amount as "Orders"
from #Temp
for xml path('Person'), root('People')
```

And for the more complex principle of a nested select doing xml inside a greater body of xml generation.  I can't remember why but the 'TYPE' statement basically tells the SQL engine it can be nested.  If you forget it and nest a select of xml inside other xml it may come out looking like garbage.

```sql
-- Maybe I need to nest XMl inside of OTHER XML
Select 
    p.person as "@Person"
,   (
    select
        o.Desciption 
    ,   o.Amount
    from @Orders o 
    where o.PersonID = p.personID
    for xml path('Order'), root('Orders'), type
    ) 
from @Person p 
for xml path('Person'), root('People')
```

Comment: thank you. However, i'm working in SQL Server and your script doesn't. I did modify the inserts but it's complaining about `SELECT AS '#Person'`

Comment: You are aliasing a temp table '#Person' where I did a table variable '@Person'.  My code should work as is in SQL Server 2005, 2008 or 2012.  The second part you can take out the code portion and paste AFTER the initial statement that does the inserts.  The key point is to know that 'for xml path...' will put things in elements unless you describe the node tree to it.  select thing as "@(something)" means attribute, "*" means text, and "path/subpath/..." is how you do nodes.  You can also nest selects of multiple for xml statements but you may need to add ', type' after it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the way that seems to be working best, in this case at least, is to use variants of **`XML AUTO, TYPE`**. As a very simple example, without `JOINs` (the `WHEREs` seem to do the trick here), is below. (Honestly, in the actual problem i'm working on, i have this plus the `JOINs` working okay, but the subtleties of `JOIN` still puzzle me, particularly when combined with this sort of problem.)

```
CREATE TABLE #Person ( PerID int identity, FullName varchar(20))
CREATE TABLE #Orders ( OrdID int identity, PerID int, OrdDt varchar(32))
CREATE TABLE #Items ( ItemID int identity, OrdID int, IDesc varchar(32), Amt int)
CREATE TABLE #Addresses ( AddrID int identity, PerID int, FullAddr varchar(50))

insert into #Person values ('Brett Doe')
insert into #Person values ('Sandy Sue')
insert into #Orders values (1, '1/1')
insert into #Orders values (1, '3/1')
insert into #Orders values (2, '1/1')
insert into #Orders values (2, '2/1')
insert into #Items values (1, 'Horse', 1000)
insert into #Items values (2, 'Hat', 10)
insert into #Items values (2, 'Boots', 100)
insert into #Items values (3, 'Belt', 20)
insert into #Items values (4, 'Pistol', 500)
insert into #Items values (4, 'Ammo', 100)
insert into #Addresses values (1, '123 Main, Somewhere, TX')
insert into #Addresses values (2, '345 Oak, Somewhere Else, TX')

SELECT Person.PerID
    , FullName
    , (SELECT OrdDt
        , (SELECT IDesc
            , Amt, Items.OrdID
            FROM #Items as Items
            WHERE Items.OrdID = Orders.OrdID
            FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
            )
        FROM #Orders AS Orders
        WHERE Person.PerID = Orders.PerID
        FOR XML AUTO, TYPE, ELEMENTS
    )
    , (SELECT FullAddr
        FROM #Addresses AS Addresses
        WHERE Person.PerID = Addresses.PerID
        FOR XML AUTO, TYPE, ELEMENTS
    )
FROM #Person AS Person
FOR XML AUTO, TYPE, ELEMENTS

DROP TABLE #Person
DROP TABLE #Orders
DROP TABLE #Items
DROP TABLE #Addresses
```

Output is

```
<Person>
  <PerID>1</PerID>
  <FullName>Brett Doe</FullName>
  <Orders>
    <OrdDt>1/1</OrdDt>
    <Items IDesc="Horse" Amt="1000" OrdID="1" />
  </Orders>
  <Orders>
    <OrdDt>3/1</OrdDt>
    <Items IDesc="Hat" Amt="10" OrdID="2" />
    <Items IDesc="Boots" Amt="100" OrdID="2" />
  </Orders>
  <Addresses>
    <FullAddr>123 Main, Somewhere, TX</FullAddr>
  </Addresses>
</Person>
<Person>
  <PerID>2</PerID>
  <FullName>Sandy Sue</FullName>
  <Orders>
    <OrdDt>1/1</OrdDt>
    <Items IDesc="Belt" Amt="20" OrdID="3" />
  </Orders>
  <Orders>
    <OrdDt>2/1</OrdDt>
    <Items IDesc="Pistol" Amt="500" OrdID="4" />
    <Items IDesc="Ammo" Amt="100" OrdID="4" />
  </Orders>
  <Addresses>
    <FullAddr>345 Oak, Somewhere Else, TX</FullAddr>
  </Addresses>
</Person>
```

I found this by searching then following linked or related questions here, such as [FOR XML EXPLICIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887344/for-xml-explicit).

A linked MSDN article, [FOR XML Query Compared to Nested FOR XML Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510436.aspx), was helpful.